# app keeps getting closed (NOT CRASH)

Tags: ios, iphone

- I have an enterprise distribution and I got it installed on a user device.
- Device was little old.
- After all the setup, when the user opens the app, it keeps getting closed and goes back to device home screen.
- It does not crash because when I open it, it authenticates and then close again.
- Its not my device but a device of one of the user.
- I can open it multiple times and each time it authenticates, connects and then close. I would assume its not crashing then I guess because of a crash in app code base.

What could be the reason?

Comment: It sounds like it is crashing. Look at the device logs.

Comment: You could be calling exit().  You're not supposed to but it's possible.  The app can be terminated due to memory usage.  That creates a type of log but not a crash specific to your app.  I suggest looking at the device's console log and see if it has clues.

Comment: i think I am looking at memory usage on the device. Because its a graceful termination....as I can open the app again and again....and it does do some n/w related tasks before closing